# Error when adding generator-jhipster via YARN

Tags: node.js, jhipster, yarnpkg

I ran the following command to install the generator-jhipster via yarn:

```
yarn global add generator-jhipster
```

After doing so, I ran into the following issue:

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=6.9.5"
```

Any clue as to how I can get around this issue?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Download latest node

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

**Node.js v5:**

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

**Node.js v6:**

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

**Node.js v7::**

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

**Node.js v8::**

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Answer (score 4):

Install node 6.9.5 or more recent.

Answer (score 2):

Update node to the latest version.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Once your install is complete, you can confirm you version with another command:

```
node -v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use

```
yarn --ignore-engines
```